# How to send asynchronous messages into a sink through a futures channel?

Tags: rust

I used to be able to do this but I'm struggling with 0.3 futures.

Here is a sink and stream I obtain from a WebSocket:

```
let (mut sink, stream) = ws_stream.split();
```

I create an unbounded channel to communicate between asynchronous tokio tasks:

```
let (unbounded_sender, unbounded_receiver) = mpsc::unbounded::<tungstenite::Message>();
```

This is the part I'm stuck on. I spawn an async task that is supposed to connect the unbounded receiver with the sink; the idea being that I send messages down the `unbounded_sender`:

```
tokio::spawn(async {
    sink.send_all(&mut unbounded_receiver);
    Ok(())
});
```

The error message says for `send_all`:

```
 " expected enum `tungstenite::protocol::message::Message`, found enum `std::result::Result`"
```

and also

```
"type mismatch resolving `<futures_channel::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<tungstenite::protocol::message::Message> as futures_core::stream::Stream>::Item == std::result::Result<_, _>`"
```

and also

```
type mismatch resolving `<futures_channel::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<tungstenite::protocol::message::Message> as futures_core::stream::Stream>::Item == std::result::Result<tungstenite::protocol::message::Message, tungstenite::error::Error>`
```

Looking [at the docs](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/channel/mpsc/fn.unbounded.html), I can see the `unbounded_receiver` implements the `TryStream` trait which is required by `send_all` so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Futures now require the unbounded_channel to implement `futures_core::stream::TryStream`

This can be accomplished as simply as wrapping each message in an Ok result:

```
    sink.send_all(
        &mut unbounded_receiver.map(Ok::<tungstenite::Message, tungstenite::error::Error>),
    );
```